# SATA-Port not working on Asus Mainboard

Tags: bios, motherboard, uefi, sata

I have a Asus Prime Z370-A Mainboard.

- 6 SATA ports: 5 SATA drives plugged on ports 2 - 5
- 2 M2 ports: 1 SSD installed on port 1 with Auto-Detection. The empty port is set to "half speed" X2 mode

The M2 SSD (SATA) on M2-Port No.1 has been installed recently. This disables SATA-Port No. 1 according to the manual of the Motherboard. Problem is that SATA port 2 also doesn't work anymore. This should not happen to my unterstanding of the manual.

I have a W11/Fedora dual boot system. Secure boot and TPM enabled.

Is there any setting that could prevent the motherboard from recognizing drives on port 2?
Is it wise to deactivate AHCI?

Comment: “Is it wise to deactivate AHCI?” - You should leave AHCI mode enabled

Comment: Check the manual. Often the chipset provides 6 SATA ports and when an M2 slot is used by a SATA SSD (instead of an PCIe) then the M2 port uses a rerouted regular SATA connection, so one regular SATA port is disabled.